# Apply a filter to a view

Tags: 7, input-formats

I have some code:

```
 http://mysite.com/node/1/edit
 <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

I have a content that processes it:

```
 http://mysite.com/node/1
 Hello World!
```

I have a view that displays the code based on context:

```
http://mysite.com/node/1/code
[[php]]<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>[[/php]]
```

How do I apply [Syntax Highlighter](http://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter) or [Geshi](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter) to the output of a view to get it looking pretty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you try to call directly the Syntax Highlighter or Geshi libraries to be readed from view templates? here is an example of Geshi (http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#basic-usage) and here another with Syntax Highlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/) Is only a suggestion (not tried).